# VBA Runtime 91 Error

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to automate a lengthy data entry process in excel.

For some reason the second time I try to find a value in a given range I get a run time 91 error. I can't figure out why this is happening. If I change the range from "AF3:AF30" to the first time I set a range("B2:AD2"), the program will continue through the line with no problem. But for some reason any range other than the first "B2:AD2" will give runtime!

Code:

```
Sub AutoFill()
Range("B8:AD57").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("B8").Select

Dim Rng As Range, cell As Range

Set Rng = Worksheets("Avon Trailer List").Range("E4:E38")

For Each cell In Rng
    Dim temp As String

    temp = Replace(cell.Value(), " ", "")
    temp = Replace(temp, "+", "")
    If temp = "" Then
        Exit For
    Else
        col = ""
        tempa = SplitMultiDelims(temp, "/,\)(")
        For i = 0 To UBound(tempa)
            If InStr(tempa(i), "A") = 1 Then
                strInput = Worksheets("Pallet Check").Range("B2:AD2").Find(tempa(i)).Address()
                lnRow = Range(strInput).Row
                strCol = Left(strInput, Len(strInput) - Len(CStr(lnRow)))
                strCol = Replace(strCol, "S", "")
                Search = tempa(i)
            ElseIf InStr(tempa(i), "A") > 1 Or InStr(tempa(i), "B") > 1 Or InStr(tempa(i), "a") > 1 Or InStr(tempa(i), "b") > 1 Then
                strInput = Worksheets("Pallet Check").Range("AF3:AF30").Find(Search).Address()
                lnRow = Range(strInput).Row
                Range("AH" & lnRow).Value() = "(" & tempa(i) & ")"
            ElseIf tempa(i) <> "" Then
                Worksheets("Pallet Check").Range(strCol & tempa(i) + 7).Value() = Worksheets("Pallet Check").Range(strCol & tempa(i) + 7).Value() & tempa(i)
            End If
        Next i
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Runtime Error 91 happens on the following line of code:

```
strInput = Worksheets("Pallet Check").Range("AF3:AF30").Find(Search).Address()
```

Comment: I believe it isn't to do with the range, but rather that you define what the variable Search contains on the first IF statement, so on the second IF statement it doesn't find anything as Search doesn't contain anything, or it contains data from the first iteration of your code.

Comment: Please enter code into the question between code tags (highlight your code and then press Ctrl + K) rather than inserting as an image. Makes it easier for others to debug as can copy paste. Also, some people may not be able to view the images.

Comment: What is search at this point?  Does it find anything?  If nothing is found the range will be `nothing` so I'd check this before trying to get the range's address.

Comment: @QHarr Thanks for the tip. I was having trouble using that (wasn't highlighting beforehand)  and was short on time. I'll make sure to use it correctly in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find().Address breaks with exception (code 91) if not found. This is because .Find() returns a range that actually points to one specific cell OR returns Nothing when not found and 'Nothing'.Address is meaningless (n.b.: null value for objects in VBA is 'Nothing'). So I would replace that line with

```
 Fnd = Worksheets("Pallet Check").Range("AF3:AF30").Find(Search)
 if Not Fnd Is Nothing then
     strInput = Fnd.Address
     ...
```

Comment: It would be worth explaining why `Not Fnd Is Nothing` will prevent the error. While this is common syntax for most experienced VBA programmers, those newer to the language will have no clue what this is doing or why it works.

Comment: .Find() returns a range that actually points to one specific cell OR returns Nothing when not found. (N.B.: null value for objects in VBA is 'Nothing'.) So you can have a chance to act differently if found or not.

Comment: I meant to add it to your answer :p. The value in SO is for all the people who later learn something new from your question. Adding that explanation to your answer (use the edit button) will help future users.

Comment: Good answer  :o)

Comment: Thank You! I turns out it .Find() was returning 'Nothing' just like you said. I thought this was impossible because while debugging I could see the value of Search and it was clearly in the range when I was looking at the spreadsheet. However, in the range I was searching for all the cells were just references to another cell in the sheet. For some reason .Find() wont look at the actual value referenced. But these cells are static, so for now I will just change them from references to actual values! Thanks again!

Comment: That's good. Would you then please click on the up arrow and then accept the answer so that I can finally cross the magic border of 50 reputations? :) Thank you.

Comment: I hit the accept button ... but my votes don’t count sadly -.-