# Find an object vertically (column) and then do a conditional check on that specific row

Tags: vba, excel

I need to find a specific word/character (Assume "X" for now) in a column and then look across that particular row to find the cell addresses which have numbers other than "0".

[Image of tabel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySSwR.png)

X could appear multiple times in that particular column and the VBA should pick every instance of that and repeat the check for numbers other than "0".

Eventually, I need a list of cell addresses which are not "0" and on the row with "X" in column one. Best if this could appear in a message box.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Code that has been tried:

```
Sub checkx() 
Dim searchResult As Range 
Dim mismatch As Range 
Dim x As Integer 
    y = 116 
    Set searchResult = Cells(1, 1).EntireColumn.Find(what:="x", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False) 
    Set mismatch = Cells(searchResult, 1).EntireRow.Find(what:="flag", LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False) 
    firstcheck = searchResult.Address 
    Do 
        Cells(y, 1) = searchResult.Row 
        Cells(y, 2) = mismatch.Row 
        x = x + 1
        Set searchResult = Cells.FindNext(searchResult) 
        Set mismatch = Cells.FindNext(mismatch)
    Loop While Not searchResult Is Nothing And firstcheck <> searchResult.Address
```

End Sub

Comment: What coding have you tried?

Comment: Sub checkx()


Dim searchResult As Range
Dim mismatch As Range
Dim x As Integer

y = 116

Set searchResult = Cells(1, 1).EntireColumn.Find(what:="x", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
Set mismatch = Cells(searchResult, 1).EntireRow.Find(what:="flag", LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)


firstcheck = searchResult.Address

Do

Cells(y, 1) = searchResult.Row
Cells(y, 2) = mismatch.Row

x = x + 1

Comment: Set searchResult = Cells.FindNext(searchResult)
Set mismatch = Cells.FindNext(mismatch)


Loop While Not searchResult Is Nothing And firstcheck <> searchResult.Address

End Sub

Comment: Where are you going to save your final result (noting that you reset `SearchResult` and `mismatch` in the loop)? You can return the results by using `Function` instead of `Sub` - or you can turn the results array into a string with another loop and then message that string. But I think that a MsgBox could look untidy with lots of results.

Comment: there wont be many results. Only around 10-20

Answer (score 0):

.Find can return `Nothing` so you must check it before using `.Address` of nothing. See this: [VBA Runtime 91 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48075587/vba-runtime-91-error/48078129#48078129)